# Verilog codes work nicely in simulation but not generating ouput on basys3 board

Tags: verilog

I am a student and learning verilog. I needed to created a D-latch simulations. My code and testbench works perfectly for simulation. However, when I implemented it to my basys3 board, I am not generating any outputs.

this is my design source:

```
module D_latch_dataflow(
input D,
input Enable,
output wire Q,
output wire Qbar
);
wire D_i;

assign #2 D_i = ~D;
assign #2 Q = ~(Enable & D_i |Qbar);
assign #2 Qbar = ~(Enable & D |Q);
endmodule
```

I tried changing

```
output wire Q,
output wire Qbar
```

to

```
output Q,
output Qbar
```

But it still doesn't work. What's the problem???

This is my testbench:

```
module D_latch_dataflow_tb();
reg D;
reg Enable;
wire Q;
wire Qbar;

D_latch_dataflow DUT (.D(D), .Enable(Enable), .Q(Q), .Qbar(Qbar));

initial begin
    #120 $finish;
end

initial begin
    D = 0; Enable = 0;
    #10 D = 1;
    #10 Enable = 1;
    #10 D = 0;
    #10 D = 1;
    #10 Enable = 0;
    #10 D = 0;
    #10 D = 1;
    #10 D = 0;
    #10 Enable = 1;
    #10 D = 1;
    #10 D = 0;
    #20;
   end
  endmodule
```

This is my simulation.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNAfx.png)

Comment: When you say "not generating any outputs" -- what are you doing, and what are you expecting to happen? Have you mapped the I/Os to pins on your FPGA?

Comment: yes i did. I should get an output(LED lights on) when I turn the switch(input). I followed a d-latch truth table, LED should light up if both my inputs are 1? but i didnt get anything.

Answer (score 4):

```
assign #2 D_i = ~D;
```

Delays aren't synthesizable -- there is no hardware in the FPGA that can be used to build a predictable unclocked delay. They should not be used outside of testbenches.

If you really want a D latch (and cannot use FPGA primitives), you will need to describe its behavior using an `always` block, e.g.

```
reg Q;
always @(D or Enable)
  if (Enable)
    Q <= D;
```

Note that this will generate warnings in many synthesis tools -- latches are considered undesirable, as they often cause timing problems.